# unit testing for clr library

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, clr

I have been trying to create UnitTest project for my C++ clr library. The UnitTest project has TESTCLASS and TESTMETHOD attributes class and methods. The library that I need to test is a clr library. Now I need to change the settings for test project to Advanced->CLR support - yes
Once I change this setting the testmethods fail to appear in the Test Explorer and if I don't the tested library is not accessible in the test project.
Is there a way to test the clr libraries using the UnitTest framework.

Comment: If you have `TestClass` and `TestMethod` attributes, you aren't using NUnit but most likely Microsoft's test framework. Please fix your tags.

Comment: Yes I have used the Native Unit test Project option. So for a clr dll, should I be using only NUnit tests??

Comment: I'd say that the test framework you use (NUnit vs MsTest) is the first decision to make. If you decide to use NUnit, perhaps you could edit the question or post a new one. But using the correct tag on a question is important since it makes the question visible to folks who follow that tag.